# Solr schema/index for CSV file with quotations and multiple commas

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Solr newbie here. I have worked through a bunch of the online tutorials and am now in the process of uploading my own data. I am having some trouble indexing in my data. I am using Solr 7.5.

Here is a look at a subset of the data. All my data is stored in CSV files:

`global_sentence_id,document_id,sentence_id,sentence,span
0,0,0,All right Jim .,"(0, 14)"
1,0,1,Your quarterlies look very good .,"(15, 47)"
2,0,2,How are things at the library ?,"(48, 78)"
3,1,0,"Oh , I told you .","(0, 15)"
4,1,1,I could n't close it .,"(16, 36)"
5,1,2,So ...,"(37, 42)"
6,2,0,So you 've come to the master for guidance ?,"(0, 42)"
7,2,1,"Is this what you 're saying , grasshopper ?","(43, 83)"
8,3,0,"Actually , you called me in here , but yeah .","(0, 42)"
9,4,0,All right .,"(0, 10)"
10,4,1,"Well , let me show you how it 's done .","(11, 47)"`

As you can see it's 5 fields. I will mainly search on the 'sentence' field. This field will contain all sorts of punctuation, multiple sentences, commas, some have quotes and others do not. Right now, if a sentence has extra punctuation (like a comma), then the sentence is wrapped in quotes to avoid splitting on the wrong delimiter (lines 3, 7, 8, and 10).

Here are my fields that I added in the managed-schema file:

`<field name="global_sentence_id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="document_id" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="sentence_id" type="pint" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="sentence" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="span" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>`

To upload the data I use this command:

`bin/post -c office2 server/solr/office2/tokenized_sentence_corpus.csv`

but do not specify any parameters.

Right now when I upload the data, I get:

`SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 (Server Error) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/office2/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":42},
  "error":{
    "msg":"(line 0) invalid char between encapsulated token end delimiter",`

followed by a long trace message.

I am confused because I am able to copy and paste all the data into the 'Documents' tab in the Solr Admin UI and it uploads everything fine and I am able to run search. I am wondering if I need to specify any parameters, and if so which ones.
Unfortunately, I am gearing up to run this on a VM, so the UI upload document features will not be useful.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Include your actual field definiton and values for the fields that doesn't generate hits. For indexing, make sure to use proper delimiter and quote characters - having [punctuation inside the string should work fine](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#csv-update-parameters) as long as the encapsulator parameter is set correctly.

Comment: I went ahead and added the field name values, along with real data I am using to give you a better sense of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have proper line endings, so that Solr isn't interpreting it as one very long line instead? That would mean that it saw `".. (0, 14)"1,0,1, ...` instead of a new line.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I have the proper line endings. I compared my data to the 'films' example data in tutorial and it is structured the same. Similarly, when I copy/paste the data into the Solar UI as is, it accepts the data without error.

Comment: Ugh, figured it out.... I had to make some edits to the file and in doing so it did not save it in UTF-8 format, instead saving it as Western Mac OS Roman. Once I saw that and switched it back to UTF, then it worked properly. Thanks @MatsLindh for making me eye my data more closely